# PIL how do I resize , split, and share an image on 1 new image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a popart image (displayed below), but I don't know how I can resize the image, then split it to 9 smaller images shared on 1 big image, that keeps the same size as the original one.
Here's the script (the part of the script that makes the popart is `def Popart()`:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as Tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog, DISABLED
import os
import ntpath
from PIL import Image

def EchelleDeGris():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            px1[x,y]=(o,o,o)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def SupprimerImage():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def Luminosite():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            px1[x,y]=(p[0]+S1.get(),p[1]+S1.get(),p[2]+S1.get())
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def AnnulerModifications():
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)

def PopArt():
    Ima2=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
    px=Ima1.load()
    px1=Ima2.load()
    for x in range(z[0]):
        for y in range(z[1]):
            p=px[x,y]
            if type(p)==int:
                p=(p,p,p)
            o=int((p[0]+p[1]+p[2])/3)
            if o<85:
                px1[x,y]=(0,0,255)
            elif 85<o<170:
                px1[x,y]=(0,255,0)
            elif o>170:
                px1[x,y]=(255,0,0)
    Ima2.save("ImageMod.png")
    im2 = PhotoImage(file="ImageMod.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)






main=Tk()

main.withdraw()
a = filedialog.askopenfilename()
main.deiconify()

main.configure(background="#a1dbcd")
main.title("Photoshop Version.Megzari")

Ima1=Image.open(a)
z=Ima1.size
nux=Image.new("RGB",(z[0],z[1]))
nuxy=nux.load()
for x in range(z[0]):
    for y in range(z[1]):
        nuxy[x,y]=(255,255,255)
nux.save("Blank.png")








if z>(400,400):
    im2 = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="ImageBlank.png")
    main.image = im2
    I2 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    I2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1, rowspan =6)
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im2)
    T1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=2, column=2)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED, length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=4, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=3, column=2)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = PopArt, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=DISABLED)
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=5, column=2)
elif z<(400,400):
    im1 = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=a)
    I1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=im1)
    I1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=1, rowspan =6)
    imt = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Blank.png")
    T1 = Tkinter.Label(main, image=imt)
    T1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=3, rowspan =6)
    B1 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Echelle de gris", command = EchelleDeGris, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", state=NORMAL)
    B1.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=0, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Appliquer Luminosité", command = Luminosite, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=2, column=2)
    S1 = Scale(main, from_=0, to=254, orient=HORIZONTAL, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39", length = 200)
    S1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    B2 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Supprimer Image", command = SupprimerImage, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B2.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=4, column=2)
    B3 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Annuler Modifications", command = AnnulerModifications, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B3.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=3, column=2)
    B4 = Tkinter.Button(main, text ="Pop Art", command = PopArt, fg="#a1dbcd", bg="#383a39")
    B4.grid(padx=20, pady=20, row=5, column=2)

s=S1.get()




main.mainloop()
```

Here's what I want to make: [image: popart]

Out of this (I know the colors are not quite perfect):[image: chev.png]

I know also that I use simple variables like `z` where I should use for example `Original_Image`.I just want to know how to resize it and split it while keeping the original image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 9 different images, each named `result0.png; result1.png; result2.png;...` so i create a list containing those images, then I open them all at once with a `for` loop, then I resize them and each one of them depending on their position, in the newly created image.
Here is the code:

```
 Img1=[None]*9
    pixels1=[None]*9
    Imaz=Image.new("RGB",(basewidth*3,hsize*3))
    pixels=Imaz.load()
    for i in range(9):
        Img1[i]=Image.open(''+dir_path+'\\PopArt\\Resized Images\\resized_image'+str(i)+'.png')
        pixels1[i]=Img1[i].load()


    for x in range(0,basewidth):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[0][x,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[1][x,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[2][x,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth,basewidth*2):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[3][x-basewidth,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[4][x-basewidth,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[5][x-basewidth,y-hsize*2]

    for x in range(basewidth*2,basewidth*3):
        for y in range(0,hsize):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[6][x-basewidth*2,y]
        for y in range(hsize,hsize*2):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[7][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize]
        for y in range(hsize*2,hsize*3):
            pixels[x,y]=pixels1[8][x-basewidth*2,y-hsize*2]
    Imaz = Imaz.resize((size[0] , size[1] ), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    Imaz.save(""+dir_path+"\\PopArt\\Result Image\\result.png")
```